# Splunk - Assigning custom time

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want my time to be the "Date" property in the following json:

```
{ "Level": "ERROR", "Date": "2021-08-20 17:21:53.6355", "Logger":.... }
```

I created a props.conf here: ...\Splunk\etc\system\local
with:

```
TIME_PREFIX=\"Date\":
TIME_FORMAT=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%4N
```

I then restarted splunk...but it's not working. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The current settings say Splunk should find a 4-digit year immediately following '"Date":', but that's not the case.  Try `TIME_PREFIX = "Date":\s"`.  There's no need to escape the quotation marks.

Comment: It's not working. Is my TIME_FORMAT needed and correct?

Comment: I'm using Splunk Enterprise and a HTTP Event Collector

Comment: Weird, I created a .txt file and added it to Splunk and did the exacly same TIME_PREFIX and TIME_FORMAT and the custom Time is working there.

Comment: I was able to solve it by putting in as a parameter in the payload.
"time":"1629565979.994"